# Path Parameters in WebSocketConfigurer addHandler in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket

- I am using "TextWebSocketHandler" for websockets and "WebSocketConfigurer" to configure the websocket.
- I have a scenario where different instances of the handler needs to be gererated.

**For example:** if I am doing auction for some items, then I need to generate seperate WebSocketHandler instances for each auctionId.
Could we attach "auctionId" as path parameter to the url so that different instance gets generated for different auction?

Or Is there any other way to achieve this?

This is how I am adding the handler:

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(websocketTestHandler(), "/websocket-test");
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to use a `TextWebSocketHandler`, you could pass the auction id as part of the URL path. You'll have to copy the path to the WebSocket session during handshake (this is the only place where you'll get access to the `ServerHttpRequest` as the handshake is an http request) and then retrieve the attribute from your handler.

Here's the implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(auctionHandler(), "/auction/*")
                .addInterceptors(auctionInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public HandshakeInterceptor auctionInterceptor() {
        return new HandshakeInterceptor() {
            public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, 
                  WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {

                // Get the URI segment corresponding to the auction id during handshake
                String path = request.getURI().getPath();
                String auctionId = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                // This will be added to the websocket session
                attributes.put("auctionId", auctionId);
                return true;
            }

            public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, 
                    WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {
                // Nothing to do after handshake
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler auctionHandler() {
        return new TextWebSocketHandler() {
            public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException {
                // Retrieve the auction id from the websocket session (copied during the handshake)
                String auctionId = (String) session.getAttributes().get("auctionId");

                // Your business logic...
            }
        };
    }
 }
```

**Client:**

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/auction/1');
```

Even if this is a working solution, I would recommend you taking a look at [STOMP over WebSockets](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp), it will give you more flexibility.

Comment: will this solution give me a seperate handler instance for each auctionId?

Comment: No, the handler is a singleton, you can have a per connection handler though (but not a per auctionId handler, this is specific to your use case and Spring is not aware of it)

Comment: Can i add these handlers through a cron job or something? It would really help if I could get different handler or handler instances for different auctions.

Comment: The easiest would be to delegate to a different instance based on the auctionId inside the handler

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to get the value from the session URI.

See example below where I check if the session contains the Box value.

URI is like /chat/{box}

```
@Override
public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
        throws IOException {

    Map<String, String> value = new Gson().fromJson(message.getPayload(), Map.class);
    String sender = value.get("sender");
    String content = value.get("content");
    String box = value.get("box");

    for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {

        LOGGER.info("Get messages on box {} and URI {}", box, session.getUri().toString());

        if (webSocketSession.getUri().toString().contains(box)) {
            webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage(sender + ": " + content + " !"));
        }
    }
}
```

In that case you don't need an interceptor.